# Are the geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue and the degree of A's minimal polynomial related?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials

Let A be a matrix over $M_n(C)$. Let $M_A(x) = \Sigma_{i = 0}^{k} a_i x^i$ be the minimal polynomial of A. Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of A such that the geometric multiplicity (that is, $n - rank(\lambda I - A)$) is $\alpha$. Are $\alpha$ and $k$ related?

Comment: Both can be nicely related to the Jordan form of $A$, but typically knowing one does not give you any information about the other.

Comment: Is there a special case where knowing one does give you info about the other?

Comment: There are a few. For example, if $M_A(x) = x-\lambda$ occurs if and only if $\alpha = n$. As another example, if $M_A(x) = (x-\lambda)^n$, then we must have $\alpha = 1$ (but in this case the converse does not hold).

Answer (score 2):

First off, it is not reasonable to expect any relation between the degree$~k$ of the minimal polynomial and the geometric multiplicity$~\alpha$ of just one of the eigenvalues$~\lambda$, as any other eigenvalues that $A$ might have have equal claims on a (special?) relation with the minimal polynomial. So I will assume that you intended the case where$~\lambda$ is the unique eigenvalue (so $A-\lambda I$ is nilpotent), or equivalently you are talking about the minimal polynomial of the restriction to the generalised eigenspace for$~\lambda$.

Even then, $k$ and $\alpha$ are not related in the sense that one determines the other or vice versa. There is more precise information from which both numbers can be deduced (but I don't think one could say in general that such a situation establishes a relation), namely the Jordan type of $A$: the partition of$~n$ given by the sizes of the Jordan blocks of$~A$. If $\tau=(\tau_{\,1},\ldots,\tau_{\,l})$ with $\tau_{\,1}\geq\cdots\geq\tau_{\,l}>0$, then the degree$~k$ of the minimal polynomial equals the largest part$~\tau_{\,1}$, while the geometric multiplicity$~\alpha$ equals the number$~l$ of parts (since every Jordan block contributes$~1$ to the dimension of the eigenspace). Only when$~n$ is small are these two number directly related due to a limited number of possible partitions: for $n\leq1$ one has $k=\alpha=n$, and for $n\in\{1,2,3\}$ one has $k+\alpha=n+1$, but for $n\geq4$ there are partitions where this relation fails, like the partition $(2,2)$ of $4$.

One can state a few generally valid relations, notably $k+\alpha\leq n+1$ (coming from the fact that the Young diagram of a partition cannot have fewer boxes than the union of its first row and column) and $k\alpha\geq n$ (coming from the fact that the Young diagram of a partition cannot have more boxes than the rectangle enclosing its first row and column). But unless one of $k$ and $\alpha$ equals $1$, $n-1$ or $n$, knowing one of them leaves more than one possibility for the other.